# What if you use the square root instead of squaring? Claim: $(M,d^\frac{1}{2})$ is not a metric space, if $(M,d)$ is a metric space.

Tags: metric-spaces

A. Let (M, d) be a metric space and $R>0$ be any real number.  Show
    that $(M, R\cdot d)$ is also a metric space.

B. Is $(M,d^2)$ also a metric space if (M, d) is a metric space?  If
    yes, then prove it.  If no, then give a counterexample.  What if you
    use the square root instead of squaring?

$\textbf{Part A:}$ Assume that $(M,d)$ is a metric space. To prove that $(M,R \cdot d)$ is a metric space, we must show that the distance function satifies the following properties:

1. $R \cdot d(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$

Since $(M,d)$ is a metric space and $R>0$ then we have $d(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$ so if we multiply the first equation by R we will of course obtained the following result: $R \cdot d(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$.

2. $R \cdot d(x,y)=R \cdot d(y,x)$

Since $(M,d)$ is a metric space and $R>0$ then we have $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ so if we multiply both sides of the equation by R we will of course obtained the following result: $R \cdot d(x,y)=R \cdot d(y,x)$.

3. $R\cdot d(x,z) \leq R \cdot d(x,y)+ R \cdot d(y,z)$

Since $(M,d)$ is a metric space and $R>0$ then we have $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ so if we multiply the both sides of the inequality by R we will of course obtained the following result: $R\cdot d(x,z) \leq R \cdot d(x,y)+ R \cdot d(y,z)$.

Hence $(M, R \cdot d)$ is a metric space.

$\textbf{Part B: Is $(M,d^2)$ also a metric space if $(M, d)$ is a metric space?}$

$\textbf{Claim:}$ $(M,d^2)$ is not a metric space, if $(M,d)$ is a metric space.

$\textbf{Proof ( by contradition):}$ Assume that $(M,d^2)$ is a metric space. Also, assume that $(M,d)$ is a metric space. To prove that $(M,R \cdot d)$ is a metric space, we must show that the distance function satifies the following properties:

1. $d^2(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$

Since $(M,d)$ is a metric space then we have $d(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$ so if we square the first equation we will of course obtained the following result: $d^2(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$.

2. $d^2(x,y)=d^2(y,x)$

Since $(M,d)$ is a metric space then we have $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ so if we square the both sides of the equation we will of course obtained the following result: $d^2(x,y)=d^2(y,x)$.

3. $d^2(x,z) \leq d^2(x,y)+ d^2(y,z)$

Since $(M,d)$ is a metric space then we have $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Hence $$d^2(x,z)=(d(x,z))^2 \leq (d(x,y)+d(y,z))^2=d^2(x,y)+2d(x,y)d(y,z)+d^2(y,z)$$ However $d^2(x,y)+2d(x,y)d(y,z)+d^2(y,z)$ will never be less than $d^2(x,y)+d^2(y,z)$. So we need to hope that they are equal. If both quantities are equal then $2d(x,y)d(y,z)=0$ which only happens if $x=y$ or $y=z$. Hence we have a contradiction because this doesn't happen for all $x,y,z \in M$.

Hence $(M, d^2)$ isn't a metric space.

$\textbf{Part B: What if you use the square root instead of squaring?}$

$\textbf{Claim:}$ $(M,d^\frac{1}{2})$ is not a metric space, if $(M,d)$ is a metric space.

$\textbf{Proof ( by contradition):}$ Assume that $(M,d^\frac{1}{2})$ is a metric space. Also, assume that $(M,d)$ is a metric space. To prove that $(M,R \cdot d)$ is a metric space, we must show that the distance function satifies the following properties:

1. $d^\frac{1}{2}(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$

Since $(M,d)$ is a metric space then we have $d(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$ so if we square-root the first equation we will of course obtained the following result: $d^\frac{1}{2}(x,x)=0 \iff x=0$.

2. $d^\frac{1}{2}(x,y)=d^\frac{1}{2}(y,x)$

Since $(M,d)$ is a metric space then we have $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ so if we square-root the both sides of the equation we will of course obtained the following result: $d^\frac{1}{2}(x,y)=d^\frac{1}{2}(y,x)$.

3. $d^\frac{1}{2}(x,z) \leq d^\frac{1}{2}(x,y)+ d^\frac{1}{2}(y,z)$

Since $(M,d)$ is a metric space then we have $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Hence $$d^\frac{1}{2}(x,z)=(d(x,z))^\frac{1}{2} \leq (d(x,y)+d(y,z))^\frac{1}{2}$$

I just don't know how to finish this proof.

Comment: Try proving that $\sqrt{d(x,y)}$ is a metric. Either you will be successful, or run in to a road block which you can use to prove it is not a metric.

Comment: I understand that but I do not know how to continue with the triangle inequality.

Comment: For $x,y$ positive, how can you compare $\sqrt{x+y}$ with $\sqrt x+\sqrt y$? (which one is bigger?) Is this relevant to your question?

Comment: Of course it is relevant to my question. I was thinking of using Holder's inequality or Minsoski but I am not sure

Comment: No, no! Square both expressions and compare. Squaring preserves the ordering of positive numbers (right?)

Comment: Now, $(M,d^2)$ is a metric space sometimes. For instance, if $d$ is discrete: $d(x,y)=1$ iff $x\ne y$. It is not a metric space some other times, but your argument does not prove this. You need to exhibit an example of a metric $(M,d)$ where $(M,d^2)$ is not metric. Your work gives you a hint on how to do that, but it is not a proof yet. (It cannot be a proof, since in some cases $(M,d^2)$ is indeed  metric.)

Comment: I want to show it is a metric all the time

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: you've got it backward. $d^2$ is not necessarily a metric. However $d^{1/2}$ is always a metric, assuming that $d$ is.

Comment: Not only that, but the "proof" you gave that $d^2$ is not a metric is not a proof, because it is false that $d^2$ is not a metric. The "necessarily" in the previous comment is there for a reason.

Comment: So what is a counterexample for $d^2$?

Comment: The real line with the usual metric (which raises the question of the examples *you* checked before asking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d^{1/2}$ were a metric, it would satisfy
$$
d^{1/2}(x,z)\le d^{1/2}(x,y)+d^{1/2}(y,z)
$$
Squaring both sides, this becomes
$$
d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)+2\sqrt{d(x,y)\cdot d(y,z)}
$$
**Edit:** This last inequality is true, suggesting the triangle inequality does hold. To prove it,
$$
d^{1/2}(x,z)\le \sqrt{d(x,y)+d(y,z)}
\le \sqrt{d(x,y)+d(y,z)+2\sqrt{d(x,y)d(y,z)}}
\\=\sqrt{(d^{1/2}(x,y)+d^{1/2}(y,z))^2}=
d^{1/2}(x,y)+d^{1/2}(y,z)
$$

Comment: It isn't. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @UsernameUnknown It *is*!

Comment: Yes but when you apply the inequality above it will show that the triangle inequality will not hold